# Treat Close Votes review the same as Suggested Edits review

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, vote-to-close

When an edit is suggested to a post, it's noted in the following way:

[image]

If you are able to use the Suggested Review queue, clicking on `edit (1)` takes you directly to the review queue location where you can perform your review.

Can the same be done for those able to review the Close Votes review queue? That is, when you click on the `close (1)` button at the bottom of the post

[image]

it takes you to that specific entry in the review queue.

This has the added benefit of leaving the reviewer in the Close Votes review queue where other clean-up might be required.

Comment: `This has the added benefit....` - I don't recall seeing another benefit in your question anywhere.  So aside from your "added benefit", why would this be preferable to the current design?

Comment: @psubsee2003: Users interested in Close Votes review counts - [and](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/custodian) [associated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/169/reviewer) [badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward) - don't miss out.

Comment: I think the greatest benefit with this is that if the users have direct access to the review queue, they can vote to leave open if they don't think it should be closed.